# Change the scan interval of ScheduledScanJob?

Tags: ibeacon-android

I use ScheduledScanJob for background scan. Now the default scan interval is 10 minutes in Android 8.0+, is there a way to change this interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Android Beacon Library, you can configure this interval to whatever value you like using `beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(20*60*1000)`.

The aforementioned example sets the milliseconds between scans to be 20 minutes.  You may increase or decrease this value from the default of 10 minutes.  Be aware however, that Android limits the frequency of scheduled jobs to be at most every 15 minutes when an app is on the background.  So any setting smaller than 15 minutes will automatically be converted by the operating system to run every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks  for you answer, it is very helpful. I have one more question. what is the "setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod" is used for, what is the difference between "setBackgroundScanPeriod" and "setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod"?

Comment: The scan period is how long the library spends actively scanning for BLE devices.  The between scan period is the time it pauses between these scan periods to save battery.

Comment: So if  that is the case, we should set beaconManager. setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(20*60*1000) to set the sets the milliseconds between scans to be 20 minutes right?